Registry Key PowerShell
When I do:
 Get-Item -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Provisioning\CSPs\.\Vendor\MSFT\SecureAssessment"

it throws an error.
When I do:
Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Provisioning\CSPs\.\Vendor\MSFT\SecureAssessment"

it returns False
When I do:
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Provisioning\CSPs\.\Vendor\MSFT\SecureAssessment"
                

it returns:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Provisioning\CSPs\.\Vendor\MSFT\SecureAssessment
    (Default)    REG_SZ    {62907C17-0036-4D44-B59C-70F2621A3EE4}
    csp_version    REG_SZ    com.microsoft/1.1/MDM/SecureAssessment

I wanted to delete and check if exists, any solutions?
For powershell script.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sharing the error you received would help us a lot, I think. Without that, we don't know what the problem is that you are facing.

Your first example uses Get-Item and uses the correct PSDrive syntax for the Registry provider (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...).  Your second example uses Test-Path which is testing for the relative (file) path .\HKLM\SOFTWARE\... rather than a registry path.  If you want to test a path, Test-Path is a good cmdlet.  If you absolutely need to use Get-Item, wrap it in a try/catch block.

HKEY_LocalMachine (or HKLM) requires administrative privileges to access.
Make sure you start Powershell (or PowerShell ISE if you're using that) as administrator before running the script.

So i answer my own question, only using [Microsoft.Win32.Registry] i was able to do this. Don't know, maybe there is other way. So function to test registry keys should work:
function RegistryKey-Test {
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$KeyPath
)

try {
    # Parse the registry path to determine the hive and subkey
    $keyParts = $KeyPath -split "\\", 2
    $hiveName = $keyParts[0]
    $subKeyPath = $keyParts[1]

    # Map the hive name to a RegistryHive object
    $hive = switch ($hiveName) {
        "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" { [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot }
        "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" { [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser }
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" { [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine }
        "HKEY_USERS" { [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::Users }
        "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" { [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentConfig }
        default { throw "Invalid hive: $hiveName. Valid hives are HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_USERS, and HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG." }
    }

    # Attempt to open the subkey
    $registryKey = $hive.OpenSubKey($subKeyPath)

    # Return true if the key exists, false otherwise
    return $registryKey -ne $null
} catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred: $_"
    return $false
}

}
